# Grabbing and Rendering Value of Dropdown Menu (React, C#)

Tags: c#, reactjs

I have a file tab on my website. I am adding a category dropdown so users can label their files according to a category so they can better organize their files. I am having trouble grabbing the value of my dropdown so that when I hit save, the category value saves and stores into the database and then renders with the rest of the well file info when reloaded.

[image: dropdown]

This is done throughout the website, but what is unique here is that the value of the dropdown is not adding directly into the interface but into an array of IWell as

```
Public Files: AttachedFile [] = []
```

[image: IWell]

The problem I am having is that though the dropdown shows up, the value of the dropdown doesnt log at all when you change the value in the dropdown and therefore when I save, it does not save the value of the category dropdown.

Here is where I am building and rendering the dropdown.

```
private handleInputChange(event: any) {
    const category = this.state.well;
    category[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    console.log(category);
    this.setState({
    isDirty: true,
    selectedFile: category,
    });
}

public renderDropdown = ({}) => (event: any) => {
    return (
        <FormGroup >
            <EInput
                type="select"
                name="Category"
                value={this.state.well.files}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange[event]}
            >
                <option value="" />
                <option value="Not Categorized">Not Categorized</option>
                <option value="Signed Documents">Signed Documents</option>
                <option value="Unsigned Documents">Unsigned Documents</option>
                <option value="3rd Party Documents">3rd Party Documents</option>
                <option value="General Well Info">General Well Info</option>
            </EInput>
        </FormGroup>
    );
}
```

To render the files info, we are just mapping over well.files and grabbing each category like so:

```
 private formatWellFiles = () => {
    const files = this.state.well.files;
    const headers = [
        "File Name",
        "Category",
        "Size",
        "Uploaded By",
        "Upload Date",
        "Download",
    ];
    const rows = files.map(f => {
        return [
            {
                content: f.name
            },
            {
                content: this.renderDropdown(f.category),
                type: 'render'
            },
            {
                content: this.renderSize(f.size),
                sortItem: Number(f.size),
                type: 'render'
            },
            {
                content: f.createUser
            },
            {
                content: f.createDate
            },
            {
                content: this.renderDownload(f),
                type: 'render',
            },
        ];

    });
```

I also cannot use something like

```
onChange={event => this.handleInputChange(event)}
```

because it will give me an error: Binds are forbidden